# How to unpublish a node programatically in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

I need to change the status of a node programmatically.

I changed the status field in the database to 0.
The node is unpublished.

The problem is that anonymous user can view the content
of the node, despite it's unpublished status ?

Answer (score 0):

Check user permissions to disallow anonymous user to see unpublished content